# Can a libgdx web application work along with web components technology?

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, libgdx

I'm working with libgdx 1.9.2 and gwt 2.6.1.

After the GWT-compilation of my java app, I get a JS script (html.nocache.js) that I can include in my html page, and visualisate in a web browser (inside a div, here it's "embed-html"). That part is working nicely.

Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>my-gdx-game</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="html/html.nocache.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <div id="embed-html"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My next goal is to use web components, and more precisely custom elements, to have a simple tag `<my-app></my-app>` in any web page to get my application.

my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
           <head>
                  <title>my-gdx-game</title>
                  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                  <script src="webcomponents.js/webcomponents.js"></script>
                  <link rel="import" href="component.html">
           </head>

           <body>
                  <my-app></my-app>
           </body>

    </html>
```

my component.html:

```
<template id="template">
    <div id="embed-html"></div>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</template>
<script>
    var helloDoc = document._currentScript.ownerDocument;
    var myApp = document.registerElement('my-app', {
    prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
      createdCallback: { 
        value: function() {
          var root = this.createShadowRoot();
          var template = helloDoc.querySelector('#template'); 
          var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);

          root.appendChild(clone);
        }
      }
    })
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="html/html.nocache.js"></script>
```

But the JS script generated by GWT-compilation has some `document.write(...)` inside; so all that is included is my empty div, my style sheet correctly loaded, and warnings: "Warning: A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored". Since it is generated, I don't think I can avoid using these `document.write()`.

If I put the `<script type="text/javascript" src="html/html.nocache.js"></script>` in the head of index.html (where it was before I tried using webcomponents), the app is not added inside the div, as it should, but under (the div and style sheet are included as expected).

And if I put the script inside the template, nothing happens.

So I am wondering if there is a way to have a GWT application working with web components, or if I should search for another way to easily include my application into external websites.

(If you wonder the reasons why I want to do so, it's because I want clients to be able to add my app easily on their own website, with only an import and a tag, the same way I could import a YouTube video or a Google map.)

Comment: There seems to be a tutorial for this (with GWT in general) here: https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/use-gwt-widget-as-polymer-web-component

Comment: Thanks, but isn't this tutorial about GWT 2.7.0? As I depend on libgdx's version of GWT, I can't use another version than 2.6.1. I'll check your link anyway.

Comment: The article sounded like GWT 2.7 might be required IIRC. You could try to change libgdx to depend on 2.7, and if it works out, perhaps create a PR, or let them know how straightforward the switch is? Maybe the libgdx people  just have not gotten around to bumping the version number, and the transition is straightforward?

Comment: Maybe I'll try in the future, but for now I don't really have time for that, plus I don't feel qualified enough as I have used these techs for a few months only. I'll try another way for the moment.

Comment: Mabe it's easy and/or you'll learn something new and interesting along the way?